# Как проверить, что число не входит в заданный диапазон?

Tags: java

Сейчас делаю через проверку вхождения

```
if ((x >= begin) & (x <= end)) {//необходимые действия} ;
else return;
```

Возможно ли в условии if проверить "не вхождение", что бы сразу сделать return и убрать блок else?

Comment: public boolean range(int begin, int end, int x) {
        return (x >= begin) & (x <= end);
    }

Comment: Как уже подсказали в комментарии выше, делаешь метод, который возвращается булевое значение, а потом просто в коде перед результатом метода ставишь знак отрицания `!`. Например вот так: `if (!range(1,5,x)) return;`. Или же можешь просто в твоем примере перед выражением в `if'e` поставить знак отрицания, получится то же самое: `if (!((x >= begin) & (x <= end))) return; `

Comment: @NarasuOo спасибо, то что надо с отрицанием! Тоже думал о нем, но не смог его поставить синтаксически правильно (ставил после if с начало).
if (!((x >= begin) & (x <= end))) return как раз мое решение!

Comment: Есть такое понятие как упрощение булевых выражений (как и арифметических). Так, `!(a & b) == !a | !b`. В данном случае `a === x >= begin`, соответственно, `!a === x < begin`. Так же и `b` преобразуется, в итоге получим ответ @Circassian, т.е. `(x < begin || x > end)` - не входит. И читается намного лучше!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x < begin || x > end) {
    // Не входит
} else {
    // Входит
}
```

Answer (score 1):

на мой взгляд самый легко понимаемый/читаемый ответ дал @NarasuOo в комметариях. Взять мое изначальное условие и просто обратить его через отрицание

```
if (!((x >= begin) & (x <= end))) return ;
```

Comment: и упростить (см мой коммент) )))

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что-то вроде

```
if(a>=100 && a<200){
    System.out.println("Число не входит в диапазон");
}else{
    //do smth
}
```

Если я правильно понял

Comment: ваше условие по сути как и мое (у меня только укороченное & и <=) и выдает вхождение - "Число входит в диапазон". Мне нужно условие в if поменять так, что бы выдавало "Число не входит в диапазон".

public class test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 4;
        if(a>=5 && a<10){
            System.out.println("Число не входит в диапазон");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Число входит в диапазон");
        }
    }
}

Comment: здесь число как раз входит в диапазон [100..200)